# Environment Variable Management

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I've been getting away from config files in lieu of environment variables.  I am encountering a few difficulties in doing so.

1. Where should I store my environment variables for my various projects?  Initially, whenever I needed to add an env var I would add `export foo=bar` in my `~\.bash_profile`.  Then I encountered variable conflicts.  Now I keep a `.profile` in each project and `source` it when I switch projects.  Is there a better/more conventional way to solve this?
2. I am storing my access tokens, passwords, etc in a plain text file (`.profile`).  Is there a more secure way?  Is this a good use case for the keychain (I am quite new to the mac world)?

Comment: There are some libs for working with environment variables, and it depends on what language and technology you are using. For example I use Node.js and dotenv (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Try to find similar lib for your technology. And read the following doc if you are not familiar with it. Perhaps you can find something new there. https://12factor.net/config

Comment: I've used the dotenv package extensively, but I have always stored my access_tokens in the `.env` file.  That is suboptimal as you are saving credentials in plaintext.  I have been storing all my credentials in environment variables, which still works with the dotenv package.  I'm just looking for a more convenient and secure way of dealing with the variables.

Comment: Got it. This is a really good question. I made some research and I've found some things which may help. I'll put the links below, just in case. I like the idea of making dotenv and node-keytar work together (perhaps this is an idea for a new open source project :) )
https://github.com/atom/node-keytar
https://gist.github.com/bmhatfield/f613c10e360b4f27033761bbee4404fd

Comment: @MaxMartynov , ajon - I tried making this case for the VScode extension: https://github.com/dotenv-org/dotenv-vscode/issues/102